# Select behavior

Tags: c, linux, select-function

It could probably be a simple question but I couldn't find a clear answer for it. I have multiple threads in c code and one of them uses select to wait for n seconds. The question that I have is that does it blocks the entire process for n seconds (like usleep) or does select blocks only the calling thread (more like nanosleep).
Thanks for the answers.

Comment: sleep does not block the entire process, or at least never in my experience.

Comment: I think it does...this is from the man page of usleep

"DESCRIPTION
       The usleep() function suspends execution of the calling process for (at least) usec microseconds."

whereas if you look at the man page of nanosleep it clearly mentions that it blocks the calling thread

Comment: you are victim of the wording. all the sleep/block functions block the current thread. there is no function which is capable of putting the whole process with many threads into sleep.

Comment: @Dummy ..yeah I do realize that now after running a test code yesterday.. Even the man pages can be misleading sometimes..anyway thanks all for clearing things up for me

Answer (score 4):

I've seen several implementations in which one thread is blocking on `select` while other threads continue processing - so, yes, it only blocks the running thread.

(Sorry for not bringing any references)

Comment: Thanks.. yes I think that should be the case but I just couldn't recall any such usage.

Answer (score 1):

The [POSIX spec for `select`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/select.html) specifically mentions "thread" in only one place, where it talks about restoring the signal mask of the calling *thread* by `pselect()`.

As with the other answers, my experience also says the answer is yes, it only blocks the calling thread.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A sloppy but still pretty conclusive test.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

using namespace std;

pthread_mutex_t cout_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *task1(void *X)
{
   timeval t = {0, 100000};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex);
        cout << "Thread A going to sleep" << endl;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);

        select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &t);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex);
        cout << "Thread A awake" << endl;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);
    }

   return (NULL);
}


void *task2(void *X)
{
   pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex);
   cout << "Thread B down for the long sleep" << endl;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);

   timeval t = {5, 0};
   select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &t);

   pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex);
   cout << "Thread B glad to be awake" << endl;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);

   return (NULL);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t ThreadA,ThreadB;

  pthread_create(&ThreadA,NULL,task1,NULL);
  pthread_create(&ThreadB,NULL,task2,NULL);

  pthread_join(ThreadA,NULL);
  pthread_join(ThreadB,NULL);

  return (0);
}
```